# Get line number from Parse crash report

Tags: ios, parse-platform, crash, crash-reports

Is there a way to extract the line number from a Parse crash report? I've uploaded the symbol files and it is using them, but all I can see are function references.

The docs don't seem to mention anything.

Answer (score 0):

Parse has exposed headers and compiled binary. You won't be able to tell the line number because your symbol files do not include parse symbol files. You need to work backwards and find a line that is exposed for your app to debug; you won't be able to find line numbers on compiled binary.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate a bit more? How would I work backwards to find the line?